# Linear Acceleration values increasing over time

Tags: android-studio, accelerometer, android-sensors

Im developing an application where im collecting linear acceleration values with my android device. Therefore I use Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION I also calculate device orientation with an sensor fusion approach using MAGNETOMETER ACCELERATION and GYROSKOP

```
 public void initListeners(){
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

    mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

    mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

    mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}

@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (startFlag == true) {

        switch(event.sensor.getType()) {
            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                // copy new accelerometer data into accel array
                // then calculate new orientation
                System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, accel, 0, 3);
                calculateAccMagOrientation();
                break;

            case Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION:
                myLinearAcceleration(event);
                break;

            case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE:
                // process gyro data
                gyroFunction(event);
                break;

            case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                // copy new magnetometer data into magnet array
                System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, magnet, 0, 3);
                break;
        }

}
}
```

In the method myLinearAcceleration, im writing linear Acceleration raw data to a txt file to store it for later analysis.

```
  public void myLinearAcceleration(SensorEvent event) {

    magnitude = Math.sqrt((event.values[0] * event.values[0]) + (event.values[1] * event.values[1]) +
            (event.values[2] * event.values[2]));

    rollingAverage[0] = roll(rollingAverage[0], magnitude);

    filtered.add(averageList(rollingAverage[0]));

    if(filtered.size() == ACTIVITY_WINDOW_SIZE ){

        double [] params = myEvaluation(filtered);
        myRecognize(params);
        myEnergie(activity);
        // params[0]=mean, params[1]=var, params[2]=stw, params[3]=RMS

        //if (params[0]){}
        counter++;

        rest.setText("RES: " + decimal.format(calories[0]));
        sedentary.setText("SED: " + decimal.format(calories[1]));
        light.setText("LIGHT: " + decimal.format(calories[2]));
        moderate.setText("MOD: " + decimal.format(calories[3]));
        vigorous.setText("VIG: " + decimal.format(calories[4]));
        total.setText("Gesamt: " +decimal.format(calories[5]));
        filtered.clear();
    }
    else{
        xSize.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
    }

    String x = String.valueOf(event.values[0])+"; ";
    //String y = String.valueOf(event.values[1])+"; ";
    //String z = String.valueOf(event.values[2])+"; ";
    String t = String.valueOf(event.timestamp)+"\n";

    try{
        fileOutputStream.write(x.getBytes());
       fileOutputStream.write(y.getBytes());
       fileOutputStream.write(z.getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.write(t.getBytes());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

For measurement times about half an hour or less everything works fine and measured values are in a typical range for the measured activitis (low for sitting, higher for walking), but if the android device is in a resting position for longer time periods linear acceleration values are constant increasing over time. As shown in the attached file. Is there a chance of a sort of drift as it appears in GYROSKOPE measurement as a consequence of poor filtering to receive linear acceleration data out of acceleration values?

Second question measurement stops sometimes without a reason when there are measurements longer than 30 minutes. Measurement is started over buttonclick and does not stop if other applications are used or display is in time out for few minutes. Any ideas why unregisterlisteners() can be called or are there other reasons for the system to unregister sensor event listeners?

```
public void unregisterListeners() {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER));

        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION));

    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE));

    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD));
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Risultati di ricerca

How can you calculate linear acceleration on devices that don't have Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION?

Comment: You can use Sensor.TYPE_ACCELERATION and apply a low pass filter to remove the gravity component of the signal. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html

Answer (score 0):

The accelerometer sensors used in cellphones today contain noise that is easily noticeable. Also, they will be very sensitive to the noise present in everyday objects, such as the table they are on which will move slightly as someone walks by. This noise and environmental noise will be in the accel output data and the way you use the values can add error to the results.

To combat this, you may want to filter your event.values[] individually, before computing the magnitude. Depending upon your application, if the system can notice that it's now just lying on a table, then it could put a low bandwidth lowpass filter (a few Hz or less) on the data from each axis before using those values in computations. That would filter out the noise. You could widen the filter bandwidth after the system wakes up, if your application needed the raw data. The system will take longer to wake up, if the wake up event is feeding from the same stream, but you could have a different data path that looked only for very large movements in order to wake up the system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you write some example code for changing filter bandwith? Because you are talking of individual filtering: would you recommend TYPE_ACCELERATION instead of TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION?

Comment: For what I mentioned, either type is OK. Let me see if I can find some code. The goal is to filter out the high-frequency noise (gravity is a large DC / low-frequency signal). From the [Android docs link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values)

    acceleration = gravity + linear-acceleration

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. One last question to you have an idea how i can implement a change of sample rate. For example while at rest just 5Hz and in motion 50Hz?